# Backend model is not specified for

Tags: magento2, admin, error

I did migration for site and when I am going to upload logo in backend,

> error: "Backend model is not specified for ", errorcode: 0

Is coming, folder have sufficient permission and user:group, Anyone have suggestion to come out from this issue.

Comment: This is resolved for me, Root cause was file_upload module was not installed on my server.